# Can't negotiate Signalr when using only webapi

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I followed the following video on getting signal and webapi running together:
[Video](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/07/webstack-of-love.html)

However, I'm unable to get it working on my solution.  I have an empty api project that has references to many other projects that have the api controllers defined for their functionality.

In one of the other projects, I wanted to add a signalr hub to communicate with the client.  So, I added signalR through nuget.

Right off the bat I began getting an OWIN error so I added the following to the app settings

`<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />`

I've added the hubcontext to the controller in question like so:

```
private readonly Lazy<IHubContext> _hub = new Lazy<IHubContext>(
    () => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TaskHub>());

/// <summary>
/// Gets the hub.
/// </summary>
protected IHubContext Hub
{
    get { return _hub.Value; }
}
```

Then in one of the api calls, I added the following code to send a message to the client:

`Hub.Clients.All.taskLoaded();`

When I started to work on the client, the connection would fail each time.  After some investigation I learned that `.../signalr/negotiate` is always returning `404`.

There is clearly something I doing wrong. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: did you `MapSignalR()` at all?

Comment: No, the tutorial and the code in github has all the mapping going through the web api routes.

Comment: I just added MapSignalR() and it seems to have worked.  I guess that's what I get for following such an old tutorial.  Thanks.  If you submit it as the answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not have mapped SignalR. Add `MapSignalR()` to your `Configuration` method in the `Startup` class.